# Get data from each row of a column in C #

Tags: c#, datagridview

It's as follows, I have a `DataGridView` with multiple columns. In each row of the `DataGridView` will be the version of the installation path of a program. With this value, I would like to use for the size of the folder and put it in the new column.

I have a method to calculate the size of a string:

```
private static long ObterTamanhoDiretorio(string tamanhoDir)
{
    DirectoryInfo dire = new DirectoryInfo(tamanhoDir.ToString());
    return dire.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Sum(fi => fi.Length);
}
```

I do not know if it's something like that that I have to use.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
{

}
```

This is what I got:

```
ObjectQuery query8 = new ObjectQuery("SELECT Description, Version, InstallDate, Vendor, InstallLocation FROM Win32_Product");

ManagementObjectSearcher searcher8 = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query8);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Program");
dt.Columns.Add("Version");
dt.Columns.Add("Installing Date");
dt.Columns.Add("Company");
dt.Columns.Add("Install Location");
dt.Columns.Add("Size");

foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher8.Get())
    {
        var paths = new List<string>();
        var installPathColumnPos = 0;
        string s = item.Cells[installPathColumnPos].Value.ToString();
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { queryObj["Description"], queryObj["Version"], FormatDateTime(queryObj["InstallDate"]), queryObj["Vendor"], queryObj["InstallLocation"], s });
    }
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

What I would like to know is how to get this value seeing on each line. If you have any ideas, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

OK, based on our comments, I believe the below is what you are after.

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("Program", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Version", typeof(double));
            dt.Columns.Add("InstallDate", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("Company", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("InstallLocation", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Size", typeof(long));

            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher8.Get())
            {
                var newRow = dt.NewRow();
                newRow["Program"] = queryObj["Description"];
                newRow["Version"] = queryObj["Version"];
                newRow["InstallDate"] = FormatDateTime(queryObj["InstallDate"]);
                newRow["Company"] = queryObj["Vendor"];
                newRow["InstallLocation"] = queryObj["InstallLocation"];
                newRow["Size"] = ObterTamanhoDiretorio(queryObj["InstallLocation"]);

                dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
            }

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

So we iterate through your results from searcher8 and add a new row to your datatable for each entry. The size column is then set from the value in "InstallLocation"

```
        private static long ObterTamanhoDiretorio(string tamanhoDir)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tamanhoDir))
                return 0;

            DirectoryInfo dire = new DirectoryInfo(tamanhoDir.ToString());
            return dire.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Sum(fi => fi.Length);
        }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've updated my question with what I got at the moment. If you can check it out

Comment: @Rekcs - OK.. I can what you are doing now. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: Ok, I will wait then

Comment: @Rekcs - Question? Does dataGridView1 get it's data from searcher8.Get()?  And are you then trying to add 1 more column for size to this data from the method ObterTamanhoDiretorio?  I can't see where dt is coming from? What type does searcher8.Get() return?

Comment: I've updated the post again with all the code. Basiccly I want to create a new column with the size of the path, you know?

Comment: In the ObterTamanhoDiretorio method it displays an error "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: @Rekcs - The code for that routine is fine. Are you getting a value in tamanhoDir when you debug?

Comment: No, the value is null

Comment: @Rekcs - Your data being returned by your searcher8 is wrong then if it's null. I'm not familiar with it. Sort out your data source and the rest will fine.

Comment: If I comment this line: newRow["Size"] = ObterTamanhoDirectorio(queryObj["InstallLocation"].ToString()); it will give me every thing

Comment: The first row does not have a location could be it?

Comment: @Rekcs - Yes.. that will be it. Just modify your ObterTamanhoDirectorio method to check if tamanhoDir is null or empty and return zero. I've update the answer.

Comment: It keeps displaying the error object reference not set to an instance of an object on this line: newRow["Size"] = ObterTamanhoDirectorio(queryObj["InstallLocation"].ToString(‌​));

Comment: @Rekcs - You need to debug and find out why! Break down the size setting into parts. Put the location from queryObj["InstallLocation"] into 1 var, then pass that into ObterTamanhoDirectorio and return its size value into another. You can then check the values in isolation. I can't get the code to break on my machine!

Answer (score 0):

```
var existingValues = dataGridView1.Rows
                                  .OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                                  .Where(x => x.Cells[installPathColumnPos].Value != null)
                                  .Select(x => x.Cells[installPathColumnPos].Value.ToString())
```

you can get the values by Linq please check this.